# Convert from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to translate these line of code from VB.NET to C# and when I check  online from

```
If (userAccountControl And 65536) Then
                                        Dont_Expire_Password = 1
                                  Else
                                        Dont_Expire_Password = 0
                                  End If
```

[Link 1](https://converter.telerik.com/)

[Link 2](https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/)

I get something

```
 if (userAccountControl & 65536)
    {
    }
```

But I get error in

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

I assume this mean

```
if (userAccountControl == 65536)
```

Correct me if I am  wrong !

Comment: "I assume this mean `if (userAccountControl == 65536)`" - **It does not.** That is a bitwise AND operator. To see what it does, convert 65536 to binary, convert the value of `userAccountControl` to binary, and then make a number only keeping the bits that are "1" in both. You'll see this operation filters out one specific bit. What's missing in here, even in your VB code, is the thing that then sees if that is not 0.

Comment: As a stylistic aside, when doing a power-of-two masking operation like this, I'd prefer to use the constant in hex form rather than decimal.  It makes it more clear.  In VB, that would be `&H10000`, in C# it would be `0x10000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# int doesn't implicitly convert to a `bool`, so you need to write your expression to handle this. In your case it would be:

```
if((userAccountControl & 65536) != 0)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `If (userAccountControl And 65536) Then` does work when `OPTION STRICT ON` is set in vb.net

Comment: This answer could use a little more explanation on the actual bitwise operation that is being performed to check a Flags type enum, because that was apparently not clear to OP.

Comment: Re @bradbury9 's suggestion: it's a disallowed implicit conversion.  (I'm not sure if `Option Strict On` allows any implicit conversions.)